# Restservice call returns 404

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am making a http.get call in angular js which returns a json file hosted locally.

**Scenario:1 -- Success**

```
$http.get("/SuccessResponse.json").success(function(jsonDataa) {
    //some code
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("error::"+status);
    return status;
});
```

The above code works perfectly fine and my code inside success gets executed alright.

**Scenario : 2 -- Failure**

However, when I host the same json on a URI, the http.get call returns 404 and alerts "error::404".

```
$http.get("http://`10.23.67.43:8080/Api/util`").success(function(jsonDataa) {
    //some code
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("error::"+status);
    return status;
});
```

Pls note when I hit the above url on my browser, it displays the JSON perfectly alright. It is only when I try to access it through rest call, it returns 404.

**Scenario : 3 -- Success**

Also, if I use a public URI (e.g. http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting) it again works alright.

```
$http.get("http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting").success(..
```

Can someone pls help in pointing out what's the issue over here?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to distinguish how it looks when you are mixing text and markup in your codetags.

However could it be so simple that you use **`** in your url?

Comment: The code has been correctly formatted now (thanks DanMan). Sorry for the earlier formatting.

Comment: why does your failing URL have backticks "`"?

Comment: @craigb - It doesn't. Stackoverflow forced me to wrap quotes around IP address. You can ignore the backticks.